# Django Project on Linode Server not pointing to the right PostgreSQL database

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, django-models

I am new to django and just uploaded a project to Linode through Nginx server. I am facing a very weird problem. When I first uploaded the project, the PostgreSQL database was "pinkgiraffedb". However, after encountering some problem on migration, I decided to create a new database called "mydb" and pull data from there. Unfortunately, the project is still pointing towards the old database. I have tried to solve the problem, but none worked so far. What I am doing wrong?

1. I have restarted nginx server several times but it didn't work.
2. Changed Debug from TRUE to False in settings.py but it didn't work.

Any suggestion would be on how to solve it would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Previously, I deleted the whole "pinkgiraffedb" database but then I started to see operational/programming error on Django admin. So created the DB again and ran migration. Restarted server several times.

['mydb' table migrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivq0a.png)

[list of databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gynYo.png)

settings.py

````
DATABASES = {
      'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'NAME': 'mydb',
         'USER': 'postgres',
     'PASSWORD': '',
         'HOST': 'localhost',
         'PORT': '5432',
     }
 }```
````

Comment: Do you have another `settings*.py` file that inherits from `settings.py` and overrides the `DATABASES` configuration?

Comment: No I don't have anything as such. Just one settings.py file.

Comment: Then somewhere you have hard coded `pinkgiraffedb` as the database name. I would do a search for that in your code.

Comment: now here's one thing I have done - changed the db name back to pinkgiraffedb. Ran the migration and manually checked the database. I see changes reflected in the database. But, it not showing on the django admin panel. I am so clueless.

Comment: Did you restart Gunicorn, or incase you're using another web server, did you restart it?

Comment: @Temi *I have restarted nginx server several times but it didn't work.* *Restarted server several times.*.  Please take the time to read the question.

Comment: At this point the only thing I can think of is to check the Postgres log and see what is hitting the database and from where.

Comment: I understand that you have restarted Nginx, and I did read your question, but there is another server which will be between  Nginx and your Django app. It could be Gunicorn, Uvicorn, UWSGI. If you don’t restart that server in between Nginx and your app, changes may not reflect.  How do you run your Django app on the Linode server?